# Rendering Problem of .AIX format from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, vector-layer, illustrator

I am trying to export Ireland Country Map on top of Satellite / Topographic base map layer in ArcGIS Pro in .AIX format to use in Adobe Illustrator. I have ArcGIS for Creative Cloud extension as well. The Problem is that when I export the Map Layout in .AIX format and Import in Adobe Illustrator I get the file that is not fully covered and missing the vector shapes.

[image]

As like the Screenshot there is a angled boundary shape in Illustrator. What I want is like this -

[image]

I tried several times with all the methods and customization but same result.

Can anybody help me resolving this?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5 and Illustrator 2020.

Comment: Is this specific to this data/layout? Was there any update being done to the Illustrator post-installation?

Comment: @YogeshChavan I tried with other data and layout but there was no issue. But yes the Other data has lot more less features than this. I  think this is a problem related to what Jeremy Wright said ...

Comment: Possibly yes, check if an update or new installation can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to update to a newer version of ArcGIS Pro/Maps for Adobe.

Illustrator has a limit of around 32k vertices in a shape, and I know we put in some changes in later versions of Pro that dice these polygons if there is more vertices than can be consumed.